# Why is unrelated code changing an std::vector's size? (causing seg fault)

Tags: c++, linear-algebra

When trying to create a Matrix from a set of column 'vectors', an unrelated std::vector is getting jumbled. I created an std::vector and initialized it with a size of 1, but it somehow becomes size 0 without being manipulated in any code. I suspected some issue with memory, but I haven't done any manual memory manipulation.

I have cut down the problematic code and posted it below.

```
#include "GMatrix.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GVector<4> temp1{std::array<float,4>{0,0,0,0}};
    GVector<4> temp2{std::array<float,4>{0,0,0,0}};
    GVector<4> temp3{std::array<float,4>{0,0,0,0}};
    GVector<4> temp4{std::array<float,4>{0,0,0,0}};
    GVector<4> temp5{std::array<float,4>{0,0,0,0}};
    std::array<GVector<4>,5> myArray{temp1,temp2,temp3,temp4,temp5};
    //Weird behavior only happens if the number of vectors > dimension of the vectors
    
    std::vector<int> problem(1); //Unused vector of size 1
    
    printf("%d-",problem.size()); // prints 1-

    GMatrix<4,myArray.size()> desiredMat{myArray};

    printf("%d-",problem.size()); // prints 0- for some reason 
    printf("%d-",problem[0]); //Seg fault here since 'problem' has size 0

    return 0;
}
```

GMatrix

```
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>
#include "GVector.h"
template <size_t R, size_t C>
class GMatrix
{
public:

    std::array<float,R*C> data;

    //0 Matrix
    GMatrix() : data{}{}
    GMatrix(std::array<float,R*C> matrixData){
        data = matrixData;
    }
    //Forms a matrix from column vectors
    GMatrix(std::array<GVector<R>,C> vectors) : data{}{
        for (int i=0;i<C;i++) { //each vector
            for (int crd=0;crd<R;crd++) { //each coordinate
                this->data[i*C + crd] = vectors[i].data[crd];
            }
        }
    }
};
```

- Note that the Matrix is stored as 1 array instead of the usual 2. For example; the item in row 2, column 1 has an index of [2*(numOfColumns)+1]

GVector

```
#include <array>
#include <stdexcept>
template <size_t T>
class GVector
{
public:
    std::array<float,T> data;

    GVector() : data{}{}
    GVector(std::array<float,T> given) {
        this->data = given;
    }

    float& operator[](size_t index)
    {
        if(index>=T){
            std::out_of_range e("Index out of range");
            throw e;
        }
        return data[index];
    }
};
```

The code should print 1-1-0- and terminate normally. Instead it prints 1-0- before getting interrupted by a seg fault.

I changed 'myArray' to have different amounts of vectors and different vector dimensions. This led me to be even more confused as the issue only happens if the vector amount is larger than the dimension of the vectors. ( std::array<GVector,B>  when B is larger than A)
This seemed to imply an issue with the GVector class or GMatrix class, but I could not find an issue with the logic. Maybe the issue is in the template declarations?

This code is supposed to generate a GMatrix 'desiredMat' from the set of column GVectors 'myArray'. 'desiredMat' has no issues and all the values are correct, but it's creation jumbles the unrelated  std::vector 'problem'.

Comment: `valgrind` and address sanitizer are going to be your best resources.

Comment: For all `std::vector` and all `std::array` element access, use `at(index)` instead of `[index]`.

Comment: Look at you `Gmatrix` constructor. Ask yourself it makes sense to take `i`, that ranges up to `C` and ...multiply it by `C`. As Mr. Spock would say: "this is not logical".

Comment: You might avoid `printf` (especially as format is wrong (`"%d"` instead of `"%ld"`)). `std::ostream` is type safe.

Comment: Side not you know you can initialize  `std::array<GVector<4>,5>` like this ` std::array<GVector<4>,5> myArray{{{0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0}}};` ?

Comment: @PepijnKramer initializer `{}` as OP uses in ctor-initializer list, does the same thing

Comment: You really should give your variables better names - that would have shown you the error easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an arithmetic error leading to out-of-bounds write in the following code:

```
for (int i=0;i<C;i++) { //each vector
    for (int crd=0;crd<R;crd++) { //each coordinate
        this->data[i*C + crd] = vectors[i].data[crd];
```

`i*C + crd` should be `i*R + crd`

Comment: I believe this has solved it. Quick question though, how did this change the unrelated vector? Shouldn't a seg fault happen on this line instead since I am accessing out-of-bounds data?

Comment: @stackuser • *Shouldn't a seg fault happen on this line instead since I am accessing out-of-bounds data?*  **No**.  Why do you believe a seg fault should happen there?

Comment: @stackuser out-of-bounds memory access is undefined behaviour and anything can happen, a common effect is to have unexpected values change in other objects nearby in memory . "seg fault" is an operating system condition where you try to access entirely outside of memory belonging to the process , which may or may not be the case for accessing out of bounds of a particular object

Comment: I was under the impression that segmentation faults represented "accessing memory that does not belong to you". The index is out-of-bounds for the array. I figured a seg fault would be thrown here since I am accessing and writing to memory that does not belong to the std::array. Edit: Just saw @M.M's message, thanks for the explanation

Comment: The memory does belong to you though, the arrays and the vector object (but not the vector's data) are all next to each other on the stack and there's nothing to stop you writing anywhere inside the stack. Segfaults only happen when you access somewhere outside the memory pages the os has allocated for you

Comment: Segmentation faults represents cases where "the operating system *detects* your program accessing memory that it shouldn't". That is one particular manifestation of undefined behaviour, but there are numerous others - one of which is that some code in your program modifies data used by an unrelated part of the same program. The OS cannot detect such cases since your program is accessing memory the OS has allocated to it - but various symptoms that can still affect your program, such as variables with unexpected values, poisoning of data used by the program, and the like.